# FormControl disabled is not working with logic

Tags: angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I want to make a field disabled from ts file.
it is working fine when I `true/false` statically. but I want to make it logically. when my form in edit mode I will make the fields editable. when the form in view mode will disable the fields.

> It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form
>   directive. If you set disabled to true
>         when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
>         you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.
>
> ```
>   Example: 
>   form = new FormGroup({
>     first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
>     last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
>   });
> ```

**Logic when i change the mode**

```
editProspectDetails() {
    this.editProspectMode = !this.editProspectMode;
    this.isProspectDisabled();
}
```

**FormControl Name:**

```
this.fb.group({
prospect_pref_name: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: this.isProspectDisabled()}),
})

isProspectDisabled(){
    return true; // working

    but i want to make it conditionally
    console.log(this.editProspectMode); // it will return : true/ false
    return this.editProspectMode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `disable()` to  disable field

try this

```
this.fb.group({
prospect_pref_name: new FormControl(''),
}
```

and in your `editProspectDetails()`

```
editProspectDetails() {
    this.editProspectMode = !this.editProspectMode;
    this.your_form_name.controls.prospect_pref_name.disable();
}
```