# Passing 'disabled' in form state object to FormControl constructor doesn't work

Tags: angular

We've seen this before:

> It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form
> directive. If you set disabled to true
> when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
> you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.

Example that is output with the warning:

```
  form = new FormGroup({
    first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
    last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
  });
```

But when I try to do it like it says, it doesn't work. So I search for the issue on SO, and I find a number of questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48860191/), but they all say to call `FormControl.disable()` manually. I'd like to not have to do that, but passing `disabled` in the 'form state object' to the constructor doesn't work. Why not?

Here is my code:

```
this.registerForm('someName', {
  firstName: new FormControl({disabled: true}),
});
```

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494968/reactive-forms-disabled-attribute), as I was asking why something doesn't work that *should*, without an additional function call, or adding things to the template. And what I discovered through my answer is pretty key, <s>and possibly an oversight in the design of Angular.</s>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reactive forms - disabled attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494968/reactive-forms-disabled-attribute)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Actually, the reason it didn't work was that I did not have 'value' in my form state object. It should have been:

```
this.registerForm('someName', {
  firstName: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true}),
});
```

See the reasoning for this requirement here: [github.com/angular/angular/pull/10994#issuecomment-244195999](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/10994#issuecomment-244195999)

Comment: Interesting someone voted this down, because this is the correct answer. Though I don't understand why a default value is required to make a field disabled.

Comment: I don't know why some stupid downvoted your question. I faced this issue just now. and it's very valid question. these voter guys think themselves like came from Mars and you must know this silly errors. you can't question on this. nonsense voters. Keep it up asking.. it's our right.

Comment: i want to underline that the **`disabled`** must be spelled exactly that - and that there is **no** symmetric _enabled_ property. Failure to notice this small detail will lead to `[object Object]` in your input https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11940

Comment: @BBaysinger because of this line: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/10.0.4/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L900

Comment: @BBaysinger I've just created an issue for this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/38178

Comment: Looks like there's a reason for this: github.com/angular/angular/pull/10994#issuecomment-244195999